# How to combine list of lists into a dictionary where the first element of a nested list is the key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to combine a list, similar to the following

```
l = [['A', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['B', '1'], ['C', '1'], ['C', '2']]
```

into a dictionary, where the first element of a nested list is the key

```
d = {'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['1'], 'C': ['1', '2']}
```

Is it possible to do this fairly easily?

Comment: Have you tried this ? Can you share your approach ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest is the following, using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
d = {}
for k, v in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

With a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), the code gets even cleaner:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in l:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: This works with 2-items sublists though, isn't it? The canhce that there can be a sublist of length 3 or more wasn't excluded

Comment: That's what the given input suggests. Behaviour for such cases wasn't specified.

Comment: I was looking for a solution for 2-items sublists only, so this one answers my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools.groupby:

```
l = [['A', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['B', '1'], ['C', '1'], ['C', '2']]
d={}
for i,k in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    d[i]=list(itertools.chain(*(p[1:] for p in k)))

>>> print(d)
{'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['1'], 'C': ['1', '2']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the notice, i have amended the code so that it will work on sorted(l)

Comment: This is at least an inherently different approach, so have an uptick, even though complexity goes from linear to log-linear ;-)

Comment: Btw, you should not use `sum(... [])` to concatenate lists. It has terrible complexity. If you are using itertools already, go with `itertools.chain` instead.

Comment: Thanks, changed my code, i prefer itertools.chains too, even though code gets pretty lengthy and more complex

Comment: `list(itertools.chain(*(p[1:] for p in k)))` is more concise and does not build two spurious lists in memory ;) `from_iterable` seems only appropriate if you want to keep a break-early option (and have an actual lazy iterator).

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion was implemented

Answer (score 0):

Here is a traditional way of doing it. Just iterate over the list and append the keys and values to the dictionary. Here is the full code:

```
l = [['A', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['B', '1'], ['C', '1'], ['C', '2']]
dictionary = {}
for key,value in l:
    if key in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[key].append(value)
    else:
        dictionary[key] = [value]
print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['1'], 'C': ['1', '2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using defaultdict can help here

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [['A', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['B', '1'], ['C', '1'], ['C', '2']]
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in l:
  d[x[0]].append(x[1])
print(d)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['1'], 'C': ['1', '2']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over l and append in the keys of the dictionbary like this:

```
d = {}
for item in l:
    

if item[0]  in d.keys():
    d[item[0]].append(item[1])
if item[0] not in d.keys():
    d[item[0]] = [item[1]]
```